# SoapUI error on request - NoClassDefFoundError

Tags: java, web-services, soap, soapui

I am new to web services and I have deployed a web service locally ( I am able to see the wsdl)
I tried to query the web service by creating a request in SOAPUI. 
The response I got back was

```
     <env:Fault>
     <faultcode>env:Server</faultcode>
     <faultstring>java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/lang/StringEscapeUtils
     </faultstring>
  </env:Fault>
```

I see a bunch of errors in the jboss console in eclipse...

```
11:53:06,226 ERROR [SOAPFaultHelperJAXWS] 
SOAP requestexceptionjava.lang.RuntimeException: 
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:org/apache/commons/lang/StringEscapeUtils
```

Can someone help me in figuring out what the problem could be?

Is something wrong with the way I setup my SOAPUI or is it I missed something in my project(web service server)

Comment: what webserver are you deploying the service to? I've had problems with some of the apache commons stuff on weblogic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need [**commons-lang.jar**](http://commons.apache.org/lang/) in your classpath

Comment: Thanks, the commongs-long jar somehow was missing from my jboss lib folder and I added it back, it worked.

Answer (score 0):

How do you exactly deploy the web service? For example, if you create an .aar archive, please verify that the corresponding jar (commons-lang.jar?) is available into the lib folder of the archive. For example:

```
your_service_root
  ->META-INF
  ->lib
     ->commons-lang.jar
  -> com
     ->bla
        ->bla
```